# Matrix-vector multiplication prints java version in stdout

Tags: scala, breeze

The following Code on Scala outputs `return java 11 instance`.

I'm using openjdk-11 and sbt 1.8.0.

```
# Main.scala
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix, DenseVector}

object Main  extends App {
    val X = DenseMatrix((1.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 3.0))
    val Y = DenseVector(0.0, 1.0)

    X * Y
}
```

```
# build.sbt
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

libraryDependencies  ++= Seq(
  "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "2.1.0"
)
```

What is the reason for this output and how can I avoid this in my projects with Breeze?

Moreover this problem reproduces with other versions of jdk, this code always prints java version from which it was built.

Comment: It's a good warning though. Instead of using optimized Native implementation. It is using J2F implemention which will be very slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that for multiplication of dense matrices Breeze uses https://github.com/luhenry/netlib with logger `dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.InstanceBuilder`

https://github.com/luhenry/netlib/blob/master/blas/src/main/java/dev/ludovic/netlib/blas/InstanceBuilder.java

```java
private static JavaBLAS initializeJava() {
  String[] fullVersion = System.getProperty("java.version").split("[+.\\-]+", 2);
  int major = Integer.parseInt(fullVersion[0]);
  if (major >= 16) {
    try {
      System.out.println("trying to return java 16 instance");
      return VectorBLAS.getInstance();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      log.warning("Failed to load implementation from:" + VectorBLAS.class.getName());
    }
  }
  if (major >= 11) {
    System.out.println("return java 11 instance");
    return Java11BLAS.getInstance();
  } else {
    System.out.println("return java 8 instance");
    return Java8BLAS.getInstance();
  }
}
```

All other logging can be switched off with `setLevel`

```scala
import java.util.logging.{Level, Logger}

val logger = Logger.getLogger("dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.InstanceBuilder")

logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "AAAA!!!") // prints

logger.setLevel(Level.OFF)
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "BBBB!!!") // doesn't print
```

[Is there a way to disable java.util.logging and enable it back later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533856/is-there-a-way-to-disable-java-util-logging-and-enable-it-back-later)

[Why are the Level.FINE logging messages not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-the-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing)

But `return java...` messages are printed not with `log`/`doLog` but directly with `System.out.println` in the static initializing block of class `InstanceBuilder`, so this is executed during initialization of the class `InstanceBuilder`.

Static initializing block can be modified only with bytecode manipulation (Javassist, Byte Buddy)

[Over riding the static block of a class in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457360/over-riding-the-static-block-of-a-class-in-java)

So the easiest is just to modify a print stream

```scala
System.setOut(new java.io.PrintStream(System.out) {
  override def println(s: String): Unit =
    if (Seq("trying to return java", "return java").forall(!s.startsWith(_)))
      super.println(s)
})
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/gk52bU4iSEebHAZPZKhaDw/5

Comment: https://github.com/luhenry/netlib/commit/8afbc6b9e0df75183f3fd3d0df33d4839d41d413

Answer (score 2):

By the way, this issue was solved in the last release of netlib

https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues/849