# Getting deadlock in java code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I have following three classes.

BaseClass.java

```
public class BaseClass {

    static {
        load();
    }

    public static void init() {
        System.out.println("base init");
    }

    private static void load() {
        System.out.println("In load method of base class");
        DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();
        System.out.println("Object creation done.");
    }

}
```

DerivedClass.java

```
public class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {

    public DerivedClass() {
        System.out.println("derived class constructor");
    }

    public static boolean isSynthetic(String _attr) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Helper.java

```
public class Helper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                BaseClass.init();
            };
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("calling static method of derived class..");
        System.out.println(DerivedClass.isSynthetic("test"));
    }

}
```

When I am executing main method from Helper.java, I am getting following output-

> calling static method of derived class..
>
> In load method of base class

After this execution is halt but the process is still running.
So it seems that there is some deadlock, but I don't understand why is that.
Help needed.

Comment: The below link answer your question .
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698516/behavior-of-static-blocks-with-inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698516/behavior-of-static-blocks-with-inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `BaseClass` is referenced for the fist time the class loader kicks in and wants to set up the class for use. So it loads the class and starts the static initializer block

```
static {
    load();
}
```

This calls the `load`-method and there you try to create an object of type `DerivedClass`. This will first try to call the `super()`-constructor, i.e. a method of class `BaseClass` - but `BaseClass` isn't fully initialized yet because its static initializer has not completed => deadlock.

**Edit:**
Based on your comment I did some more research. Actually, things are not quite as simple as I assumed. The JVM is capable of dealing with recursive initialization so there is no problem in the single-threaded case. A description of the class-initialization-process can be found in section 5.5 of the JVM-specification.

What is the culprit here is actually a race-condition between the two initialization-processes.

Thread 1 reaches `DerivedClass.isSynthetic("test")`, and starts the initialization of `DerivedClass`.

Meanwhile thread 2 reaches `BaseClass.init()`and starts the initialization of `BaseClass`.

While initializing `DerivedClass` thread 1 recognizes it has to initialize the superclass. Since initialization of `BaseClass` is already in progress by thread 2 thread 1 has to wait for it to complete.

While initializing `BaseClass` thread 2 reaches `DerivedClass dc = new DerivedClass();`. Since initialization of `DerivedClass` is already in progress by thread 1 thread 2 has to wait for it to complete.

So actually this is a classical deadlock where two threads try to enter two critical codepaths ("initialization of class X") in different order (BaseClass->DerivedClass vs. DerivedClass->BaseClass) and ending up waiting for each other.

Adding some `Thread.sleep(100);` in the proper places will also show you that this is really a race-condition. During my tests sometimes the program completed successfully despite the cyclic dependency during initialization.

Comment: What you explained seems possible, but then why  `System.out.println(DerivedClass.isSynthetic("test"));` here static method of derived class was also in deadlock state. and when I remove the call to static method of derived class, then execution works fine and I get the output as:  </br>
calling  
In base class  
derived class constructor  
Object creation done.  
base init

Comment: @Rahulkhandelwal You are right, the JVM is more sophisticated than I thought. I added some explanation for the real cause.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is really helpful.