# How do initializer blocks behave when extending classes?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}

class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("A static initializer block");
    }
    static void methodOfA() {
        System.out.println("A static method");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("A non-static initializer block");
    }
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A constructor");
    }
    public A(String a) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static {
        System.out.println("B static initializer block");
    }
    static void methodOfB() {
        System.out.println("B static method");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("B non-static initializer block");
    }
    public B() {
        super("test");
        System.out.println("B constructor");
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

A static initializer block
B static initializer block
A non-static initializer block
test
B non-static initializer block
B constructor

But I would expect it to be:

A static initializer block
B static initializer block
A non-static initializer block
B non-static initializer block
test
B constructor

Because, as far as I know, initializer blocks are loaded before the constructor.

I have been browsing google and stackoverflow for an answer but have been unsuccesful.

Any clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Behavior of static blocks with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10698516/behavior-of-static-blocks-with-inheritance)

Comment: As `A` must be fully initialized before `B` it is reasonable to assume that the `A` constructor is called before `B`s initializer.

Comment: @andreoss Thanks, but unfortunatel that doesn't answer my question because that question is specifically on how static initializerblocks work. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 3):

The superclass constructor executes before the subclass constructor and a non-static initializer is executed immediately before the constructor is. Hence, in your output, "test" appears before "B non-static initializer block".

Answer (score 2):

static initializer blocks are only executed once when a class is initialized by the JVM whereas instance initializer blocks are executed every time an instance of a class is created. Instance initializer blocks execute before the code in the constructor **but after the call to parent's class constructor** (i.e. after `super()` call).

Java compiler copies the code of instance initializer blocks in to every constructor. Instance initializer block code is placed after the `super()` call. So following code:

```
{
    System.out.println("B non-static initializer block");
}

public B() {
    super("test");
    System.out.println("B constructor");
}
```

will be transformed in to:

```
public B() {
    super("test");
    System.out.println("B non-static initializer block");
    System.out.println("B constructor");
}
```

This explains why `test` is printed on the console before instance initializer block of the `B` class executes.

Comment: Nothing is copied into constructor at the JVM level.. also, instance blocks are executed before the constructor; moreover, even statically bound (initialized in the code) instance variables are executed before the constructor's body.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri _The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors_ - this quote if from [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri _also, instance blocks are executed before the constructor;_ - i think that is what i said in my answer. Code in the instance initializer block is executed before the code in the constructor. Only exception is the call to `super()` which executes before the instance initializer block.

Comment: That seems right. I accidentally read your code in the opposite order.